# How to add the same element a certain number of times in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I want to have a failsafe feature for my arraylist, that if it fails to have a certain size, I would like to set all values to 0 up to a certain index. I cannot find anything that allows me to do this, however.

I have "bruteforced" it so far, but as I want my minimum to go higher and higher it this can't be sustainable:

```
if(challenges.size() < 4){
    challenges.clear();
    challenges.add(0, 0);
    challenges.add(1, 0);
    challenges.add(2, 0);
    challenges.add(3, 0);
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop and `list.set(i, 0)`?

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, it's really not. Its a question as to what I can do with an Array, and that's pretty clearly stated. Not sure how you missed that. Updated it with the code though. No need to be snarky. I have been working all day, and didn't feel like pulling up my laptop, so I posted from my phone. Much harder to format from my phone, so I didn't think the code was necessary.

Comment: @slider Must have been to tired to think of this! Thanks, this was the solution.

Comment: `challenges.addAll(Collections.nCopies(4, 0));`

Answer (score -1):

```
int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 4;
if (challenges.size() < endIndex) {
    challenges.clear();
    IntStream.range(startIndex, endIndex)
            .forEach(i -> challenges.add(0));
}
```

**Or** if re-assigning is ok, then this might be more efficient:-

```
int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 4;
if (challenges.size() < endIndex) {
    challenges = IntStream.range(startIndex, endIndex)
            .mapToObj(i -> 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Or** the best way would be to use the good old for-loop:-

```
int endIndex = 4;
if (challenges.size() < endIndex) {
    challenges.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < endIndex; i++) {
        challenges.add(0);
    }
}
```